# VB Script to find the existance of a macro in microsoft word document

Tags: vbscript

I want to write a VB Script which will check in a word file about the macro name we pass from vb script whether it exists or not. It return the result to VB script and i want to call this VB Script from the JAVA and whatever the result is it should appear in JAVA. tell me how to call the VBScript from java and how to pass the name of the macro and path of the ".dot" stylesheet from java to vb script.

Answer (score 0):

Your title doesn't really match the rest of the question or the flags, so I migt be answering the wrong thing.

[This](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) page contains information about how to execute VBScript from Java. And then if you send the macro name etc as command line parameters to the script you should be able to pick those up inside the script using `Wscript.Arguments`. [Here](http://leereid.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/sweet-vbscript-command-line-parameters/)'s a blog post that shows how to do that.